# MySql Connection on a Webserver to a JSON file instead of an Database

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, database

I have a normal node.js server connecting to a database :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({

  host: "...",
  user: "...",
  password: "...",
  database: "...",
  multipleStatements : true
});
//Launch Server on port 3000
var server = app.listen(3000, listening);
function listening() {
  console.log("Server was launched");
}
```

If i wan´t to run this Webserver just local I´d be cool to export the Database as a JSON and replace the connection details with the JSON file.
Is anything like that possible ? I didn´t find any solution as yet.

All the best
Tim

Comment: Whether or not that approach makes sense depends on your type and size of your database. If you only want to store the data from a single table or view with a limited number (i. e. several thousand, not millions) of records then there might be a solution. Otherwise it is going to be a nightmare, as you will be transferring and loading too much data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb). It is a local JSON database and pretty useful for storing data without setting up a database server.